# Java + Lombok, is there a @Delegate with chaining capability for void return types

Tags: java, lombok

Given

```
class A { 
  @Delegate()
  Property property;

}
```

and

```
class Property {

    void a() {...}
    void b() {...}

}
```

You can do `new A().a();` but not `new A().a().b()`;

Is that possible to achieve for delegates in lombok?

Comment: you are aware that 'void' means -> returns nothing? if you don't return anything, what is it you are trying to call a method on?

Comment: Do you *really* have to chain those calls? What stops you from just declaring `new A()` as a variable?...